# Como recorrer valores de array tras insertar un valor en un lugar ocupado

Tags: c#, array

En una aplicación de consola, donde tengo un arreglo tipo string, una de las operaciones permite insertar valores en lugares que están ocupados, por ejemplo:
Tengo un array de la siguiente manera:  `{cero, uno, 0, 0 ,0}`.

Los ceros son valores nulos, si se quiere insertar otro valor como por ejemplo 'ncero' en la posición cero, los valores actuales deben recorrerse, quedando de la siguiente manera:

`{ncero, cero, uno, 0, 0}`

El problema es a la hora de recorrerlo cuando tienen mas de un valor ocupados, si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

```
if (respuesta == "2")
{
    bool señal = false;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("En que posicion desea insertar el dato?");

    respuesta = Console.ReadLine();//Lee el dato de manera String

    i = int.Parse(respuesta);//Convierte la posicion en tipo Int

    if (i > 9)//Si la posicion ingresada es mayor que el tamaño del array manda error
     Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una posicion valida");
    else
     Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor que desea agregar");
     respuesta = Console.ReadLine();//Lee el dato a ingresar

        if (Nombres[i] != null)//Si en la posicion deseada hay ya un valor
        {
          for (int x = i + 1; x < Nombres.Length; x++)//Recorre todo el arreglo

       {
    }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu código? Además no se entiende la notación que estas usando, si es código c# por favor coloca un código válido.

Comment: @Kevin M., el código está incompleto; por lo que entiendo , necesita reemplazar _en una posición dada_ el valor que se ocupa en ese espacio del arreglo. Revise el siguiente [enlace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array) para entender el concepto de los arreglos.

Comment: debe ser un array? cualquier ventaja de rendimiento que dé sobre una lista, lo perderás realizando el shift.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que recomendaria es que no uses un array, sino que implementes un `List<>`
este tipo de listas permite insertar un valor en la posición que necesites.

Podría ser algo como esto

```
List<string> Nombres = List<string>();

// resto del codigo

if (i > 9)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una posicion valida");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor que desea agregar");
    respuesta = Console.ReadLine();//Lee el dato a ingresar

    if (Nombres[i] != null)//Si en la posicion deseada hay ya un valor
    {
        Nombres.Insert(i, respuesta)
    }
}
```

Al usar una lista cuentas con metodo

[List.Insert (Método) (Int32, T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Cuando necesitas trabajar con coleccines en donde la posición es dinámica lo recomendable es una `List<>`

Si despues necesitas un array podrias usar el [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sobre la lista